# What is the hotkey in Xcode to open the function list & MARKs list in the current file editor

Tags: xcode

Instead of mouse clicking the section in Red box here, is there a hotkey for it in XCode?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`control-6`.

Everything in that bar is found in the **View➡️Editor** menu.

"Hotkey" is a Microsoft term. They are called "keyboard shortcuts" in the Apple ecosystem.

[image]